# meaning of "tentative balance"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

when we say "tentative balance of butterflies" what can "tentative" stand for? Does it mean "natural", "experimental", or "unstable"?

Context:

The painter Madeleine Strindberg uses fMRI scans as a starting point to make delicate paintings of the fine traceries of the central nervous system. She reconfigures specimen sections in order to render the mysterious patterning of the brain as the abstract matter from which processes emerge. Traverse sections of the medulla oblongata float like butterflies over a golden yellow background, an adulation of form for its own sake. It also helps to know that the medulla oblongata controls bodily movement and the maintenance of equilibrium, so the butterflies’ tentative balance is more meaningful intellectually.

Comment: needs more context

Comment: I imagine the original author was reaching for *tenuous balance*.

Comment: [Tentative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tentative) doesn't mean any of those things, so it's impossible to say what the author intended. Could you edit your question to include four or five sentences so we can see how he used it? I'll put the question on hold for the moment, or it will simply garner guesses.

Comment: @Andrew Leach the context is added  ;)

Comment: It most likely means "unstable" and "fleeting".